# Stack same z-index with same top:0 position on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stack two elements to both show on the screen.

Element A and Element B has the same `z-index: 2000` and also same `top:0`  and `position:fixed`.

When it rendered on the browser, I can only see the `element A`.  The `element B` is hide behind element A because they has the same css styles.

What I want, is to both render them stack one after another.  On the browser I should see element A at the top and element B after element A.

Here's the style

```
position: 'fixed', top:0, width: '100%', 'z-index': '2000'
```

Comment: do you have a set height?

Comment: no, there's no height.  If I changed the "top:100" for element B then they're both show on the screen.  I know the problem is because they both has the "top:0" but I don't know how can I set a style to make them display one after another.

Comment: @fkuafusi well is there any reason in particular that you are using fixed positioning? typically what you describe is achieved by using the default `position: static`, and no `top` value.

Comment: Yes, I want both elements to stick at the top, while the rest of the page content scroll behind them.

Comment: share your html code

Comment: @fkaufusi, you might wrap your A and B and set the wrapper fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position fixed is relative to the viewport.
You should set `element a` height and `element b` `top: {element a height}`.

```css
.a {
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  z-index: 2000;
  background: violet;
}

.b {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
    <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
```

But actually it sounds that `sticky` position will be a better fit:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;

}

.c {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  min-height: 10px;
}

.d {
  background: yellow;
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.e {
  height: 10000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
<div class="e"></div>
```